# Alexa skills: How to prompt user for response after audio player finish playing a file

Tags: echo, alexa-skills-kit

I am very new at developing Alexa skill. I know that I cannot do speak, re-prompt, etc at Audioplayer.PlaybackFinished, so is there a way to ask user for response or invoke another intent after an audio file is finished playing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [SSML audio tag](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#audio) if you want to get an interaction.

```
<speak>
  Hello World!
  <audio src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/01/mobile-apps/dex/ask-customskills/audio/lang-ssml/InParisTheyPronounceItParis._TTH_.mp3" />
  What do you want?
</speak>
```

---

```
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(
        `Hello World! <audio src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/01/mobile-apps/dex/ask-customskills/audio/lang-ssml/InParisTheyPronounceItParis._TTH_.mp3" /> What do you want?`
      )
      .reprompt("What do you want?")
      .getResponse();
```

And make sure your mp3 is [properly encoded](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#h3_converting_mp3)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an audio player directive and it seems so, then simply no.

You can not prompt any response simply because the audio player is not part of your skill. Your skill just starts the audio player and its session ends afterwards.